# Cantor Measure as the Limit of Simple Functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu_C$ be the Cantor distribution. That is, the unique distribution whose cumulative distribution function is the Cantor function. If we think of integration w.r.t. $\mu_C(x)$, that is, the differential $d\mu_C(x)$, can we represent this as the limit of $\phi_n(x)dx,$ where $\phi_n$ is a family of Lebesgue simple functions. If so, does anyone know of such a sequence $\phi_n$?